# simple nginx handler to do simple task and return

Tags: http, nginx

I'm trying to do something that seems easy, so I think I should ask for help, because it's looking complicated. Usually this means I'm asking the wrong question.

I want to tell nginx about a new location handler.  It will just use grpc to ask a back end how to respond. (Probably nginx has something even niftier than grpc, but I start out thinking how I think for other components in my system.)

Looking through lists of nginx modules, I'm thinking I'll have to write a new module from scratch. Surely that is wrong.

Very specifically, I receive an http request that looks like this:

```
http://www.example.com/some-text-that-might-be-long
```

and I want the nginx handler to make a call to my service with that URL and the http request headers.  It will get back a reply telling it how to respond.  Typically that will be either a request to 302 to some other URL or another status code with some content.

Any pointers much appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide more info on what you are trying to do? NGINX can proxy requests to MySQL using the [stream](https://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_core_module.html) module, should also work for PostgreSQL.

Comment: In the PostgreSQL case, it looks at http://example.com?abcd, looks up abcd in the database, find that it corresponds to fghijk, and composes an http response with fghijk. It also records some monitoring data.

Comment: Both cases could be the grpc case, of course, and that might simplify my life.

Comment: Reduce it down to what urls A, B, C etc should look like and what you'd expect to get. That determines what middleware (if any) is needed.

Comment: @Melvyn Right, I've simplified the question, removing the postgresql part (because that much logic should really not be embedded in the nginx handler).  So now the question is really just about a grpc handler.

Comment: Hmm, now that I've simplified the question, I see [this issue](https://github.com/grpc/grpc.github.io/issues/230) as well as [this](https://nghttp2.org/blog/2015/03/24/proxying-grpc-with-nghttpx/) rather helpful article, which might be a good path forward.  I'll report back.

Comment: Yes, the second one is the way to go, since you're simply mapping URLs to URLs and the backend speaks http (http2). Postgres doesn't speak http, so you need some translation. Things to consider are performance and security, as always when deciding what to use. [ngx_postgres](https://github.com/FRiCKLE/ngx_postgres/) and [OpenResty](http://openresty.org/en/) may be of interest here as alternatives for grpc.